# How to convert XML files to INI files

Tags: c#, xml, ini

I would like to get help how to convert a XML file into INI file.

Why INI? The settings of my current machine is base on .ini file, after conducting research, I always see about INI to XML but not XML to INI file, if you can give me reference, I would love too.

The XML isn't fixed, meaning, the *code* must be read and converting it.

If someone can help me, thanks!

For Example:

**XML FILE**

```xml
<root>
    <General>
        <TaxRate>"3"</TaxRate>
    </General>
    <Settings>
        <POSName>"DOT"</POSName>
    </Settings>
    <Coupon>
        <Success>"True"</Success>
    </Coupon>
</root>
```

**INI FILE**

```
[General]
TaxRate=3

[Settings]
POSName=DOT

[Coupon]
Success=True
```

Comment: "The XML isn't fixed": So what rules will apply to the conversion?

Comment: Inform yourself about XSLT: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp

Comment: And what exactly is stopping you from reading XML and writing INI? Neither of those parts are particularly challenging.

Comment: It's something like, if the XML is edited which is "Unknown information" ex:
the xml added more items, then the concept of what Im going to build is gonna convert all or new information that's inside the XML into .INI file and add it.

** <General>
     <TaxRate> "3"</TaxRate>
 </General>**
`[General] DiscountRate=10`

Comment: @Sebastian, gonna read for it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that xml can have a farily complicated structure, that could not be simply transposed to INI ? You need to specify some restrictions, like  "direct child nodes of root are the [category] entries of my ini", and "direct child nodes of the categories are the entries"

Comment: I really shouldn't point this out, but if you know your XML is formatted exactly like that, you could just do it using regular expressions...

Comment: @Pac0, I don't know, so I asked, thanks for the info! :) I would search deeper, right now I need thoughts, so I ask for you guys.

Comment: @DylanNicholson, It's just an example, I'm not the one who will input the data's in XML, they told me that, I need to convert it into INI, so all the machines will be updated. Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Load it into an `XDocument` then try something like

```
string.Join("\n", xDocument.Root.Elements().Select(c => "[" + c.Name + "]\n" + string.Join("\n", c.Elements().Select(s => s.Name + "=" + s.Value)))));
```

Only works with XML files 2 levels deep. Use at your own risk.

Comment: As an added note, this won't work with repeating elements. Traditional ini supports neither duplicate keys inside one section, nor duplicate sections.